# Microsoft.data.edm.dll being copied from "somewhere" on build in VS 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, visual-studio-2013

I am collaborating with another developer using VS2013 and VSO.

The solution runs fine on his machine but mine complains of:
"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Edm' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

We've isolated this to the fact that 1 project within the solution is copying version 6.5.0 of this DLL into the bin folder upon build which is overwriting the 6.5.2 version required by other parts of the solution.

We aren't sure where it is finding this version of the DLL as it only happens on my build. We are using various nuget packages but all are up to date and identical between our machines.

Does VS pick up DLLs such as this from "standard locations" on the machine somwehere? I searched my hard drive and found various versions of the DLL going from 2.0 to 2.6.2. The most suspect of these seems to be:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Packages\Microsoft.Data.Edm.5.2.0\lib\net40

Is there anywhere I can tell VS not to get this DLL from some random location?

Thanks

Comment: Did you set the reference to be specifically version x?

Answer (score 0):

Try to build it with detailed MSBuild information (Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run) and then copy the output and search for `Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll` to find where it's copied and where does it come from.

To force the copy of the correct version, you can add an assembly redirect to the app.config file of the project (you may already have this section if you have used NuGet):

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.2.0" newVersion="5.6.2.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

This will force the use of the correct version on compilation and will not try to get the other version from the GAC or the system `PATH` environment variable.